# Slicing lists for getting just quarter of them in the same length

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list with lengths of `A`. Is there a way using slicing to take just every fourth value but maintaining it's length? For example, If this is my list:

```
A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....]
```

I want to use slicing to receive:

```
A = [0,0,0,0,4,4,...]
```

Using the `[::4]` is doing the job for the taking every fourth value, but without the other values I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> [v for v in A[::4] for _ in range(4)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 12, 12]
>>>
```

I should mention that this rounds the result list length up to a multiple of 4, so you always get 4 of each value included in the result.  If you want to drop the extra values at the end, you can append `[:len(A)]` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

you could do :

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
repeatedA = [ A[(i//4) * 4 ] for i in range(len(A))]
```

the `i//4` here allows to get the quotient of the division of the index by 4, then `(i//4) * 4` allows us to find the closest multiple of 4 to `i` smaller than `i`, so here 1,2,3 are not dividors of 4 but 0 is , which is the closest multiple to them, it's the same with 5,6, and 7, 4 is the closest multiple ( given that it should always be smaller than either of them ), it's equivalent to `i - i%4`, which allows us to round i down to the closest dividor of 4 given that `i = 4* (i//4 ) + 4%i`

Comment: Answers are always more helpful, if they are not just code, but contain some explanation.  Please could you supply some here.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints elements of A if their index residual from division by 4 equals 0.

Instead of `i%4==0` you may enter `i%4==1` or 2 or 3 if you need different offset.

```
A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
print ([A[i] if i%4==0 else 0 for i in range (len(A))])

[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 12]
```

If you want to repeat each fourth value 4 times, try this:

```
print ( [A[i//4*4] for i in range (len(A))])

[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 12]
```